# Selecting a row in gridview then passing the selected row to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, row, aspxgridview

I am writing a web application in ASP.NET using C# with SQL Server.

Basically I want to be able to select a specific row in a `GridView` and pass the primary key from that row to another page which contains a series of text boxes and labels,  I want these to be populated with the data from the selected row.

The main reason for me doing this is because I have a lot of fields in my table and I need to expand on the fields in the `GridView` for editing etc.

I have researched a bit about the select statement in ASP.NET but I can't figure out how to pass that information to another page.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply guys, appreciate it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this:

First, in your gridview, add the primary key in the datakeys,

```
DataKeyNames="Id"
```

and add an event for the selection,

```
OnSelectedIndexChanging="OnRowSelected"
```

Then in your code behind:

```
protected void OnRowSelected(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the datakey of the selected row
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(grdCompany.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);
    // Redirect to second page
    Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx?Id=" + id);
}
```

Then in your SecondPage.aspx, you can get the id from the selected row by:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["Id"];
```

Comment: Hello Ben, Is it possible to come to the first page with the selected record from the second page?

Comment: Hello @Vinay, yes it's possible. It's just a matter of passing the right keys to the querystring.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way if you are not using DataKeyNames.

```
int RowIndex;
protected void gvName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvName.SelectedRow;
    string name = gvName.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Text; //Gets column

    //With DataKey
    string name = gvName.DataKeys[RowIndex]["TicketId"].ToString();

    Response.Redirect("~/secondpage.aspx?ServiceCenter=" + name);
}
protected void gvName_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //Gets Gridview row number when clicked
    RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Session. So I imagine that you have some variable

```
var currentGridViewRow = GridView.SelectedRow;
```

You can insert to the session information about this row:

```
Session["currentGridViewRow"] = currentGridViewRow;
```

After that in your second code behind you get the information from the session.

```
var currentGridViewRow = Session["currentGridViewRow"];
```

Please remember that this is very simple and general approach. It is good practice to write some class which will manage your session.

Helpful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Another great way of doing it, thank you very much for your solution